# OWL restriction and open world assumption clarification: max 1, exactly 1

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, turtle-rdf

Say we have the definitions:

```
Product hasPrice exactly 1 xsd:decimal
Product hasPrice max 1 xsd:decimal
```

With the open world assumption, we can define a product without specifying the price, like:

```
A a Product;
rdfs:label "Apple"@en .
```

My understanding is:

With `exactly 1` definition, we are saying this product's price is unknown.

With `max 1` definition, we are saying a product can have no price.

Am I right?

---

I got myself confused when defining

```
Service has some gr:UnitPriceSpecification
Service has exactly 1 Provider
ComputeService has max 1 TransactionsUnitPriceSpecification
```

Need to get my head around all the possible situations.

Comment: basically, yes and for `max 1` the price could also just be unknown

Comment: Is there a specific reason/use-case for asking this question?

Comment: Thanks, would you like to re-post as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open world semantics trips up many people. You are certainly not alone :D

Here is a quick overview of the meaning:

```
Product hasPrice min 1 xsd:decimal
```

states that `Product` has at least 1 price. However, this allows for `Product` having multiple prices.

```
Product hasPrice max 1 xsd:decimal
```

states that `Product` has at most 1 price. However, this allows for `Product` having no prices at all.

```
Product hasPrice exactly 1 xsd:decimal
```

states that `Product` has at least 1 price and at most 1 price.

I have written about this in more detail on my [blog](https://henrietteharmse.com/2019/02/23/understanding-owl-min-vs-max-vs-exactly-property-restrictions/).